# Git initiating clone visual studio 2019 hangs forever

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019, git-clone

I'm trying to `clone` project through visual studio 2019 and when hitting clone button it hangs forever and nothing happens

[image]

Have you any idea how should i resolve this issue?